# Does Haskell "hackage" overlaps two different type signature with same name?

Tags: haskell, stream, monads, st-monad

While I was exploring the library, I saw the following code.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/src/Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Fusion.html#unstreamChunks

look at `unstreamChunks`.

This code bundles the Stream of Char into chunks and returns it as Text. It creates and uses mutable arrays in the process.

What I think odd is the type signature of `inner`, which is `inner :: MArray s -> Int -> s -> Int -> ST s Text`. (Hover your mouse on `inner` and see the type signature if you want to).

So, (the type `s` representing the state of the `MArray s`and `ST s Text`) and (the type `s` representing the state in the `Stream`) are the same as "s". (The third argument type `s` is from `Stream next s length`.)

`unstreamChunks` uses `runST`. It means that `s` from the `ST s Text`, which is identical to `s -> (s, Text)`, should cover `RealWorld`. Cause `runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a` and it consequently apply `s -> (s, Text)` to `s` = RealWorld.

However, `s -> Step s Char` in the `Stream Char` depends on concrete type `[Char]` in a specific application.
I'll show you an example below.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/src/Data.Text.Lazy.html#pack
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-2.0.2/docs/src/Data.Text.Internal.Fusion.Common.html#streamList

`pack = unstream . streamList . map safe`.

`s -> Step s Char` from `Stream Char` is

```
   next [] = Done
   next (x : xs) = Yield x XS
```

It totally depends on concrete type `[Char]` and won't work for `RealWorld`, or it won't type check for `runST`.

I can't figure it out how it works!! But it works well.
So, I think that two different type parameter `s` from `inner` is not the same.
There's nothing to do with `Stream Char` and `State s`.
There's no code combining two different `s` type values.

The type signature of `inner` is even not an Haskell code. It's just a preview from hackage.

So, I concluded that hackage's auto generated type signature doesn't mutate original type parameter name even if it overlaps.

I want to get confirmation that my guess is correct.

Also, if I'm wrong and the two types are actually the same, I would appreciate it if you could explain why the code works well.

Comment: Those are not the same `s`, they're just namesakes.

Comment: You can have two functions of the same name in different packages, if that is what you are asking.